# 'x' and 'p' must have the same number of elements even though data frames have the same length

Tags: r, dataframe, p-value, chi-squared

I'm running into an issue with my chisq.test() function where I'm passing in the data frames of each parameter (the p parameter is also decimals that add to one), but I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out this problem. Even though they are data frames of the same length, with the same amount of observations, I am getting flagged for these issues over and over again.

```
# chisq.test(x = observed, p = expected/126) 
# the expected are in probabilities rather than counts

df <- matrix(observed_values)
df2 <- matrix(expected_values)

chisq.test(x = double(df), p = double(df2))
```

I have tried to divided all my elements in df2 by 126 (the sample size), changed the data frame to have three variables with one observation, and I have looked on here.

Here is the error message:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please try to avoid posting code/errors as images - copying the text into a code block is much preferred.  We can't replicate your issue without your data, so could you please try to create a reproducible example as per this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: If there are any NA's then the eventual data supplied may not have the same lengths. Have you tried coercing the dataframe to a matrix?

Comment: Scratch my previous comment (about `data.frame`), it does work once coerced internally to a `matrix` (which is done automatically in `chisq.test`).

Comment: Ryan Hedburg, I've tried several other ways and the only way I can see to reproduce that error is when `x` is a vector (not a frame, as suggested above) and `x` and `p` are different lengths. Please [edit] your question and add the output of `dput(observed_values)` and `dput(expected_values)` to a [code block], it'll help us immensely to help you!